# math function -> addition hh time with basic javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I do a calculation of more than two time hour values like `(10:00 + 02:30 + 03:00) = 15:30` in a 24h time format with javascript?

Please see attached code snippet and you can see what the goal is. Unfortunetely I don't know how I can get it done.

Currently I am using the following code to calculate three text fields.
See also [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7k6L38g/)

```js
function output(){
  var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
  var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
  var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
  document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = (parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)) + parseInt(value3);
}
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value3" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result1"> </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to minute first then convert to hour when showing back.

```js
function output(){
  var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
  var value1Sec = getMinuteValue(value1);
  var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
  var value2Sec = getMinuteValue(value2);
  var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
  var value3Sec = getMinuteValue(value3);
  document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = getTime(value1Sec+ value2Sec+ value3Sec)
}

function getMinuteValue(val){
 var arr = val.split(':');
 var value = +arr[0]*60 + +arr[1];
 return isNaN(value) ? 0 : value
}

function getTime(val){
 var min = (val%60);
 min = min<10 ? ('0'+min) : min;
 var hour = (parseInt(val/60))%24;
 hour = hour<10 ? ('0'+hour) : hour;
 return hour+':'+ min;
}
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="time" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="time" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value3" type="time" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result1"> </p>
```

Comment: thanks looking neat! but how can I limit the result to 23:59 and let it continue from 00:00 when 23:59 is exceeded?

Comment: thanks a lot. Looking good, except minutes. 00:03 + 10:00 + 00:00 gives 10:3

Comment: @Alex check again

Comment: Check my answer. No time math required.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be easier to implement. You need to do the format checking though, I would suggest using onblur event instead of onchange which fires everytime a key is pressed. Here is a working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/r7k6L38g/10/

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
function output(){
    document.getElementById('result1').textContent = 
    Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs).reduce(function(ac,d,i,a){
    ac += d.value.split(":").reduce(function(ac,d,i){
            return ac += !i ? +d : +d/60
        },0);
        return i === a.length - 1 ? ac%24 : ac;
  },0);
}
```

Do the formatting of the end result as you want, I left it decimal, otherwise do (ac<<0)+":"+(ac%1 * 60 << 0) at the end

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the time math manually, you can let javascript engine do the math. convert first value `value1` into a dummy Date format and add other 2 values' hours and minutes to the first date.

Add hours to date by multiplying `3600000` to `hour` and `60000` to `minute`

```js
function output(){
  var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
  var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
  var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
  document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = new Date(new Date('2018-04-26 '+value1).getTime()+ value2.split(':')[0]*3600000 + value2.split(':')[1]*60000 + value3.split(':')[0]*3600000 + value3.split(':')[1]*60000).toString().split(' ')[4];
}
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value3" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result1"> </p>
```